# Inserting data in to new table from two older tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to know if it's possible to insert data from two different tables (by selecting which columns I want) and inserting them in to a new table.

Here is the query I have, it doesn't seem to work.

```
INSERT INTO book2.orders_bought (`id`, `sold_order_id`, `sold_order_item_id`, `item_id`, 
`status`, `card_name`, `supplier_name`, `total`, `date_ordered`)
SELECT `order_id`, `bought_order_id`, `oi.id`, SUBSTR(sell_link, 97, 20), `status`, 
`card_name`, `supplier_name`, `total`, `date` 
FROM book1.orders_buy, book1.order_items oi
```

Note: the only field I want to extract from the table order_items is `id`

Comment: How is books1.order_buy connected to book1.order_items? Is order_id in book.order_items? If so you need a JOIN. Also helpful if you indicate the error.

Comment: @tofutim order_items.id = orders_by.id, are you saying this will only work if I join the tables?

Comment: are order_buy and order_items one-to-one? better show the schema for orders_buy and order_items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO book2.orders_bought (
   `id`, `sold_order_id`, `sold_order_item_id`, `item_id`, 
   `status`, `card_name`, `supplier_name`, `total`, `date_ordered`)
SELECT 
   `b.order_id`, `bought_order_id`, `oi.id`, SUBSTR(sell_link, 97, 20), 
   `status`, `card_name`, `supplier_name`, `total`, `date` 
FROM book1.orders_buy b
LEFT JOIN book1.order_items oi ON oi.order_id = b.order_id
```